# Javascript functions not called in correct order, need async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

The code snippet below is not running in the proper order... the for loop is calling the downloadFile function call over every iteration before any other functions can resolve, which is affecting the number of links returned to the final callback.

What I need is an loop iteration to finish only once the appendLinksList function has resolved and returned a link. I'm assuming I need async to block the functions? How would I use async to get the proper flow instead of the downloadFiles function being called before anything else can resolve a value?

**Note that the callback functions have been defined above this code snippet**

```
const entries [ /* Array of objects containing a path_display property */];

let links = [];

for(let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

            const appendLinksList = link => {
                if(i !== entries.length - 1) return links = [...links, link];

                return callback(null, links);
            };

            const downloadFile = path => {
                Dropbox.filesGetTemporaryLink({ path })
                .then(file => {
                    return appendLinksList(file.link);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return res.status(500).json(err.message);
                });
            };

            downloadFile(entries[i].path_display);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your loop in an immediately invoked async function.

```
const linksResolved = await (async() => {
    let links = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {

            const appendLinksList = link => {
                if(i !== entries.length - 1) return links = [...links, link];

                return callback(null, links);
            };

            const path = entries[i].path_display;
            await Dropbox.filesGetTemporaryLink({ path })
                .then(file => {
                    return appendLinksList(file.link);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    return res.status(500).json(err.message);
                });
            };
        };
    return links;
})()
```

However, the result you want (links) will forever be a promise.
Can only be resolved in an async function. Or you can call a callback with links from inside the immediatelyInvokedAsyncFunction

Comment: how do you have an await outside the wrapped function? I thought await can only be used inside an async function

Comment: That's the thing. In order to do async operations in order. The whole process needs to be run async.